# How do I check transaction status using go-ethereum simulated back-end?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, testing, revert-opcode

Using the `go-ethereum` simulated backend, I would like to:

1) Instantly commit a transaction so that it either succeeds or reverts in a given simulated blockchain.

So far I'm using `sim.Commit()` to trigger this.

2) Verify whether the transaction succeeded or reverted. Is there an API available to help with this?

I've noticed there is a `TransactionByHash()` function that does return an `isPending` variable, however, this variable only indicates whether the transaction is part of the pending pool and is not correlated with success or failure.

I have the transaction hash and the simulated back-end object available.